# Background Image in WebView showing in Simulator, but not on Device

Tags: html, ios, css, webview

I am trying to display a background image from a html document in a UIWebView. The image is displayed perfectly, with text on top when I run it in the iOS Simulator (or Google Chrome), however if I run it on my iPhone the text appears without the background image.

I am using this Swift code to load the html document into the WebView:
`webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(htmlCodeFilename, ofType: "html")!)!))`

Then my html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head> 
 <style>

 body {
 background-image: url("img.png");
 background-size: 425px 640px;

 font-size: 130%
 }

 </style>
</head>
<body>

    <p>One evening as the sun went down</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The font is increased on the device when run, so I know its running the `<style>` tag.
The image is currently in the same folder as my html and swift files. But what is very worrying is that if I completely delete the image from the project, the image still appears as the background in the Simulator. It is only if I fudge the call within the CSS code (e.g. `background-image: url("ig.png");`), that the background image doesn't appear in the Simulator.

If anyone knows how to display the image on the device or knows what is going on at all, I would really appreciate the help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the device never recognized the image, or why it still showed up on the Simulator when I completely deleted the image from my project.

However, solved the problem by simply adding a `UIImageView` behind the `WebView`. 
Then in the `View Controller` implementing this function:

```
func setupWebViewClearBackground(webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.opaque = false
    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

And calling it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupWebViewClearBackground(webView)

    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Math Background")

    loadHTML(webView,htmlCodeFilename: "htmlCodeFilename")

}
```

Thanks for all the fish!

Answer (score 1):

I converted the local images into [base64 format](https://xaviesteve.com/pro/base64.php) and they work on the device now. Consider this as a quick fix.